# C dynamic macro choosing

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to invoke a macro by building its name during runtime. I want to have a list of macros that follow the same name rule `ERROR_MSG_X` where X is the error code and to invoke them according to a variable. I have the following function:

```cpp
void    print_error(int e)
{
    printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, ERROR_MSG_#e); //not proper syntax
}
```

The header would be something like:

```cpp
# define ERROR_MSG_1 "Failed to open file.\n"
# define ERROR_MSG_2 "Failed to read file.\n"
# define ERROR_MSG_3 "Failed to execute abc.\n"
...
```

I tried messing with `#` and `##` but didn't get the results I wanted.

I have a lot of constraints on what I can and can't do such as no external functions, no multiline macros, no parameterized macros, no global variables, etc. Is there a way to calculate the name of the macro with the value passed or do you have another suggestion on how to do this? I could have an array with the msgs and pass it to the function but I really didn't want to do it that way plus I would have to have the error codes sequential or waste memory to store them.

Comment: `I'm trying to call a macro by building it's name during runtime.` Macros don't exist at runtime.

Comment: you can't.  the pre-processor has no idea what the value of `e` is.  it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Sooo why not just an array? `I could have an array with the msgs and pass it to the function` Yes, have an array with the msgs __in the function__ and use it. But `I have a lot of constraint` - what is the reason of these constrains?

Comment: @KamilCuk This is an assignment and the constraint come from the entity that will evaluate it. My problem with the array method is that to have 10 different msgs it would be fine but as soon as I get a few hundred I would need multiple files just to declare it. (I can only have 5 functions per file with 25 lines per function). I don't agree with a lot of the constraint and they suck :(

Comment: how many macros can you make?
I have a hacky idea, you could define all the elements of the array in a macro and just define it like so:
`const char arr[] = {MACRO};`

Comment: @tkausl & MFisherKDX Thanks. Guess I'll have to come up with another way of doing this

Comment: @Cufox I have no limit in terms of macro creation. If I get what your saying is having something like `# define ERROR_MSG_1 "Failed to open file.\n"` `# define ERROR_MSG_2 ERROR_MSG_1, "Failed to read file.\n"` and so on? I'll give this a shot

Comment: *"I have a lot of constraints: ... etc."* Hard to work without knowing the exact constraints.

Comment: If the "entity" that is evaluating your work is encouraging you to horribly abuse the pre-processor, you should push back.  Bad design should be challenged.  If that "entity" is attempting to teach you the language, consider alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are expanded before compiling, so there is no macro expansion in the compilation iself.  They are there to save you typing, to make your code more readable (sometimes) and to avoid error prone C constructs to be less error prone (also sometimes), by controlling all repeated sequences inside the macro definition and allowing you to specify things in only one place.  But once the macro expanded code gets into the compiler, there are no macros anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### Proposition 1: X macros

It is possible to use the concept of [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) widely used in Linux kernel source code. The idea is to provide multiple expansions of a macro named `X`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// The X-macro
#define LIST_OF_ERRORS                             \
       X(ERROR_MSG_1, "Failed to open file.\n")    \
       X(ERROR_MSG_2, "Failed to read file.\n")    \
       X(ERROR_MSG_3, "Failed to execute abc.\n")

// 1st definition of X to define enum error codes
#define X(e, m) e,
enum {
LIST_OF_ERRORS
};
#undef X

// 2nd definition of X to define cases in a switch
void print_error(int e)
{
#define X(e, m) case e: printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, m); break;
  switch(e) {
    LIST_OF_ERRORS
    default: printf("[ERROR] : unknown code (%d)\n", e);
  }
#undef X
}

int main(void)
{
  print_error(ERROR_MSG_2);
  print_error(ERROR_MSG_1);
  print_error(ERROR_MSG_3);
  print_error(10);

  return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc err.c
$ ./a.out 
[ERROR] : code (1)
    Failed to read file.
[ERROR] : code (0)
    Failed to open file.
[ERROR] : code (2)
    Failed to execute abc.
[ERROR] : unknown code (10)
```

**N.B.**: This partially answers the question as I use a multi-line macro...

### Proposition 2: `##` operator

In this proposition you need to use "hardcoded" constant error numbers passed as parameter to `PRINT_ERROR()` macro otherwise the compiler will complain. The compiler will also complain if you pass unknown error numbers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERROR_LABEL_0  "Error message#0\n"
#define ERROR_LABEL_1  "Error message#1\n"
#define ERROR_LABEL_2  "Error message#2\n"
#define ERROR_LABEL_3  "Error message#3\n"


#define PRINT_ERROR(e) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, ERROR_LABEL_##e)


int main(void)
{
  PRINT_ERROR(2);
  PRINT_ERROR(1);
  PRINT_ERROR(3);

  return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
$ gcc macro.c
$ ./a.out
[ERROR] : code (2)
    Error message#2
[ERROR] : code (1)
    Error message#1
[ERROR] : code (3)
    Error message#3
```

But if you use a variable or a constant out of range, the compiler complains:

```c
[...]
int main(void)
{
  int err = 2;

  PRINT_ERROR(2);
  PRINT_ERROR(1);
  PRINT_ERROR(3);
  PRINT_ERROR(err); // <---- Compilation error
  PRINT_ERROR(10);  // <---- Compilation error

  return 0;
}
```

The errors displayed by the compiler:

```
$ gcc macro.c
macro.c: In function 'main':
macro.c:15:72: error: 'ERROR_LABEL_err' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'ERROR_LABEL_1'?
   15 | #define PRINT_ERROR(e) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, ERROR_LABEL_##e)
      |                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
macro.c:25:3: note: in expansion of macro 'PRINT_ERROR'
   25 |   PRINT_ERROR(err); // <---- Compilation error
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
macro.c:15:72: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   15 | #define PRINT_ERROR(e) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, ERROR_LABEL_##e)
      |                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
macro.c:25:3: note: in expansion of macro 'PRINT_ERROR'
   25 |   PRINT_ERROR(err); // <---- Compilation error
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
macro.c:15:72: error: 'ERROR_LABEL_10' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'ERROR_LABEL_1'?
   15 | #define PRINT_ERROR(e) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, ERROR_LABEL_##e)
      |                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
macro.c:26:3: note: in expansion of macro 'PRINT_ERROR'
   26 |   PRINT_ERROR(10);  // <---- Compilation error
```

Comment: This would be exactly what I needed if I hadn't so many restriction. Unfortunately with those illogical constraints I can't use this. I'll save it though for the future as this seems useful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about the second proposition with ## operator ?

Comment: That would go against the "no parameterized macros". What I'm going to do is simply add a string param and use the appropriate macro when calling print_error. Not exactly what I want but it works... Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

as I said in the comments:
you offload loading the array to the pre-processor, it's pretty much like writing out the array but it takes less lines in the function.

```
void print_error(int e){
    const char *errors[] = {ERRORS};
    printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, errors[e]); 
}
```

and for the `ERRORS` macro:

```
# define ERRORS "Failed to open file.\n",\
                "Failed to read file.\n",\
                "Failed to execute abc.\n"
```

edit:
I'd also advise putting the error codes in an `enum`, that way you can determine the number of errors and make sure a bad error doesn't get called, when doing this I usually write an entire function that turns error codes into strings, but as you said that might be too long.

Comment: This would work except for two problems. First I can't have multiline macros but that would be solved by doing macros that call each other like I said in the response to your first msg. The second problem would be that all error codes need to be sequential and I wouldn't be able to skip to the 100, 200, etc if I wanted to organize them.

Comment: what do you mean by "sequential" and "skip" can you elaborate?

Comment: Multiline macros are not an issue.  Splitting the macro's expansion across multiple lines serves strictly for human readability.  You can instead join all the lines together into one if that satisfies a requirement.

Comment: Assuming i have 99 errors I would need to have error codes in range 1-99 but if I want all file related errors to be in range 1-99, all graphical errors to be 100-199, all libraryX errors to be 200-299, etc I wouldn't be able to or I'd have to populate the missing slots with empty string/NULL

Comment: Well, what is the actual requirement for the assignment, @fletcher? It's unrealistic to try to plan for more than that when you're forced to work under so many artificial constraints.

Comment: yup it sounds very unrealistic, over-engineering it only to use it for 10 errors in the end sounds like a waste of your time.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The assignment is a recreation of the game Wolfenstein3D. The thing is a want to be able to handle errors in a "proper" way. Being able to have error codes in certain range to distinguish between categories and appropriate messages amongst other things.

Comment: @Cufox These restrictions apply to all C projects so I wanted to have a system I could just almost copy past from project to project

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
void print_error(int e) {
    const char *p = "";
    if (e == 1) p = ERROR_MSG_1;
    else if (e == 2) p == ERROR_MSG_2;
    else if (e == 3) p == ERROR_MSG_3;
    printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, p);
}
```

or the same with `switch case:`. I would do:

```
void print_error(int e) {
    static const char *const strs[] = { ERROR_MSG_1, ERROR_MSG_2, ERROR_MSG_3 };
    const char *p = (1 <= e && (e - 1) < sizeof(strs)/sizeof(*strs)) ? strs[e - 1] : "";
    printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, p);
}
```

You could write a macro:

```
#define GET_ERROR_MSG(e)  ( \
((e) == 1) ? ERROR_MSG_1 :
((e) == 2) ? ERROR_MSG_2 :
((e) == 3) ? ERROR_MSG_3 :
"")
printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, GET_ERROR_MSG(e));
```

A more confusing macro then it's worth it:

```
#define CASE_ERROR_MSG_(e, x)  ((e) == (x)) ? ERROR_MSG_##x :
#define GET_ERROR_MSG(e)  ( \
   CASE_ERROR_MSG_(e, 1) \
   CASE_ERROR_MSG_(e, 2) \
   CASE_ERROR_MSG_(e, 3)\
   "" )
printf("[ERROR] : code (%d)\n\t%s", e, GET_ERROR_MSG(e));
```

Either way, you **have to** enumerate all messages in one place one way or another, for the runtime part to find it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this method due to the constraints. Thanks for the suggestion though.